# Remove the Selected Item From ListView

Tags: c#

How can I remove a selected item from a listview?

Comment: You might wanna accept some answers for your questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UWP remove selected item from listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49532128/uwp-remove-selected-item-from-listview)

Answer (score 36):

```
foreach ( ListViewItem eachItem in listView1.SelectedItems)
{
    listView1.Items.Remove(eachItem);
}
```

where listView1 is the id of your listview.

Answer (score 12):

When there is just one item (`Multiselect = false`):

```
listview1.SelectedItems[0].Remove();
```

For more than one item (`Multiselect = true`):

```
foreach (ListViewItem eachItem in listView1.SelectedItems)
{
    listView1.Items.Remove(eachItem);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
listBox.Items.RemoveAt(listBox.SelectedIndex);
```

Comment: private void iAttachmentDel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            listBox.Items.RemoveAt(listBox.SelectedIndex);
        }

Answer (score 3):

Well, although it's a lot late, I crossed that problem recently, so someone might cross with this problem again. Actually, I needed to remove all the selected items, but none of the codes above worked for me. It always throws an error, as the collection changes during the foreach. My solution was like this:

```cs
while (listView1.SelectedIndex > 0)
{
    listView1.Items.RemoveAt(listView1.SelectedIndex);
}
```

It won't throw the error as you get position of the last selected item (Currently), so even after you remove it, you'll get where it is now. When there is no items selected anymore, the SelectedIndex returns -1 and ends the loop. This way, you can make sure that there is no selected item anymore, nor that the code will try to remove an item in a negative index.

Answer (score 2):

```
listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Where(T => T.Selected)
    .Select(T => T.Index).ToList().ForEach(T => listView1.Items.RemoveAt(T))
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, it helped me with some modification to my needs:

 var item = lstResult.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Where(b => b.Content.ToString().Contains("Progresso"));

if(item.Count()>0) lstResult.Items.Remove(item.ElementAt(0));

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to remove item(s) from a `ListView` control (that has `GridView`) (in `WPF`)--

```
var selected = myList.SelectedItems.Cast<Object>().ToArray();
foreach(var item in selected)
{
    myList.Items.Remove(item);
}
```

where `myList` is the name of your `ListView` control

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dgr in dgvComments.SelectedRows)
            dgvComments.Rows.Remove(dgr);
```

Comment: I think the question is about ListView.