# listview display error with List strings in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, outofrangeexception

I have a listView1 in C# WinForms which displays 2 List

```
List<string> pths;
List<string> rec;

public void Disp ()
        {

            DisplayListInColumns(listView1, pths, 0);
            DisplayListInColumns(listView1, rec, 1);
        }
private static void DisplayListInColumns(ListView listView, List<string> values, int columnIndex)
        {
            for (int index = 0; index < values.Count; index++)
            {
                while (index >= listView.Items.Count)
                {
                    listView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem());
                }
                ListViewItem listViewItem = listView.Items[index];
                while (listViewItem.SubItems.Count <= columnIndex)
                {
                    listViewItem.SubItems.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem());
                }
                listViewItem.SubItems[columnIndex].Text = values[index];
            }
        }
```

I am using the global List to make the changes and also display it in the listview1 but only after the user clicks apply_button will the changes be saved (on to a xml).

The Edit and Add details button is working fine and displaying perfectly. But when I delete the data, I am thrown an error.

The following is the delete action:

```
//Configuration - DELETE button
        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string select = null;

            if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                select = (listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text);
            }
            int count = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index;

            if (select != null)
            {
                pths.RemoveAt(count);
                rec.RemoveAt(count);
                string s = String.Join("; ", pths.ToArray());
                string r = String.Join("; ", rec.ToArray());
                //MessageBox.Show(s);
                //MessageBox.Show(r);                                
            }
            Disp();
        }
```

I think after few tries, I am going wrong with the index. Even after deleting, while debugging I get the `listView.Items.Count = 5.` 
I am guessing the count is still 5 (sample - 5 string within the list) when after deleting it should reduce to 4 and the index 0-3 accordingly. 
I am getting the following eror

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException at pths.RemoveAt(count)
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
```

As an alternate I tried `pths.Remove(select);` but did not resolve this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You hope that the index in the ListView matches the index in the List<>.  That stops working when you remove an item.  Since you remove it from the List<> but not the ListView.  So eventually "count" is going to be larger than the last index in the List<>.  Kaboom.

Comment: Thank you @HansPassant I understood the error, just confused about a proper solution.

Comment: It isn't clear to me why you leave a deleted item in the ListView.  Removing it as well will be the simple solution.  If you need to leave it in then you'll also need a dictionary that maps listview items to list items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to reload your list...

```
//Clear it
listView1.Items.Clear();
//reload it.
listView1.Refresh();
```

Comment: worked like a charm... Thank you. I would also thank mike-c and moncaded for their inputs as well.

Answer (score 2):

Change your if statement

```
if (select != null)
```

to this

```
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(select))
```

Your text property won't be null, it will be empty string and so you are entering that section when you think you aren't.

EDIT:

Based on your comments, i'm going to direct you to this solution instead, replace your entire delete function with something like this:

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  foreach (ListViewItem eachItem in listView1.SelectedItems)
  {
    listView1.Items.Remove(eachItem);
    if (pths.Any(o => o == eachItem.Text))
    {
        pths.Remove(eachItem.Text);
    }
    if (rec.Any(o => o == eachItem.Text))
    {
        rec.Remove(eachItem.Text);
    }
  }
}
```

You may need eachItem.Value instead, but I think .Text will work.

NOTE: 
This answer I absolutely just copied from here (I take no credit for this solution):

[Remove the Selected Item From ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425623/remove-the-selected-item-from-listview)

Comment: I changed the if statement: Initially the List showed <img src="http://oi48.tinypic.com/24waukj.jpg"> and after I delete the first item <img src="http://oi49.tinypic.com/k9nw8.jpg"> The last item is a copy and the whole list is just shifted up.

Comment: Delete only the selected items. User selects a single item (I have disabled multiselect) and clicks delete. The selected item should be deleted from the list<strings> and similarly be updated in the listview. The Disp() just iterates through the list displaying the contents

Comment: just saw it, tried it and realized...  pths is a list. SelectedItems work only for listView.

Comment: That makes it even easier. CHeck the update. You just need to iterate the selected items in your listview.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27036/discussion-between-vivian-lobo-and-mike-c)

Answer (score 1):

You need to verify your `SelectedItem` first before trying to remove it from the `List`.

```
   private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string select = (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0) ? (listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text) : null;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(select))
        {
            listView1.BeginUpdate();
            pths.Remove(select);
            rec.Remove(select);
            listView1.EndUpdate();

            string s = String.Join("; ", pths.ToArray());
            string r = String.Join("; ", rec.ToArray());                     
        }
        Disp();
    }
```

Comment: I tried this solution as well, I am able to remove the item fromt he List<string> which is the pths and rec, because when testing I display string s and r and it gives me the list deleting the selected item. Just that the listview is not updating properly.

Comment: Updated the solution... What collection is your ListView using? (pths or rec) also, how is it not updating properly?

Comment: It is a collection of strings. `List<string> pths = new List<string>(xml.xmlreader("C:\\product.txt", "Name"));
            List<string> rec = new List<string>(xml.xmlreader("C:\\product.txt", "Recurse"));`

Comment: sorry @moncaded The updated solution did not work as well, if you need any further information from the form I can paste it.

Comment: Shouldnt you only update the Display whenever an item is deleted? Try moving Disp() after string.join (inside the if check).