# How to disable item at particular index of a listview in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

guys after processing the item of a listview i was removing it using

```
  lstSqlStatements.Items.RemoveAt(selected_index);
```

However this was completely disrupting my index trace as it was removing the item fron the listview.

Is there any ways to just DISABLE the item in the listview ?(so that the user does not click again on it)

Comment: Is it a checkbox that you want to disable in ListView?

Comment: Please show the markup of your ListView and which items do you want to disable

Answer (score 2):

tried this? Just googled it.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d3c68d8a-89d3-4de6-b9f9-4d617ffdeb77/disable-item-selection-of-the-listview

```
private void listView1_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
        if (e.IsSelected) e.Item.Selected = false;
    }
```

Comment: @AnoushkaSeechurn http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425623/remove-the-selected-item-from-listview ?

Comment: I do not want to REMOVE IT, i just want to DISABLE it. can view it but cannot click on it(cannot select it).

Comment: @AnoushkaSeechurn Sorry I read it wrong. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472172/how-do-you-disable-an-item-in-listview-control-in-net-3-5 ?

Answer (score 0):

This will hide the 3rd row as in UI.

```
protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
        {
            int index = e.Item.DisplayIndex;
            if(index==2)

            e.Item.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```